# BigDataLite 2.4.1 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: oracle, out-of-memory, bigdata, nosql

I am beginner trying the Oracle Big Data NoSQL MoviePlex Hands-On Labs and have been facing the same error of trying to load the index page after I have loaded the movie data into the NoSQL. The following are the error message that had been shown at the JDeveloper.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
>     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
>     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>   Caused By: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
>     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
>     at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"
>   Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"
>   Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"
>   Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"
>   Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"
>   Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"
>   Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"
>   Exception in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" 
>   Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'"

I have even have increased the Base Memory to 12000MB as I was told that it might resolve the problem but there would still be this error.

These are the tools and platform that I'm using:- 
BigDataLite 2.4.1 - Oracle VM VirtualBox 
Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1

Link to Hands-On Lab: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/bigdata/articles/intro-to-oracle-nosql-db-hol-1937059.pdf

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks,
Ann

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the file `setDomainEnv.sh` under `/home/oracle/.jdeveloper/system11.1.1.6.38.61.92/DefaultDomain/bin/`, and edit it.

Locate the string `WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"` (I found it twice) and add `"-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"` after `-Xmx512m`, so that it will look like:

```
WLS_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m".
```

After that, restart JDeveloper.